# ClearOS SMTP Server Setup using Gmail SMTP

Tags: smtp, gmail, clearos

How to set up ClearOS SMTP server using gmail SMTP? 
I'm using ClearOS as IMAP mail server. Receiving mails from pop hosting is no problem. But to setup SMTP for client using the same server is a challenge. Anybody knows how to use Google mail account as an SMTP server for ClearOS? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's for ClearOS, but here is link explaining how to do SMTP one for you: https://www.siteground.com/kb/google_free_smtp_server/ and link two: http://mail.google.com/mail/signup

Hope this helps!